# Pointer to NSTreeController newly created item

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstreecontroller

Does anybody know of a good workaround or hack to get a pointer to the newly created node from an NSTreeController add: or addChild: method?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have it select inserted objects, and then call selectedObject.